# Regex to split string into parts of contiguous alphanumericness

Tags: regex

I'd like to split a string into substrings of consecutive letters that share some property: specifically alphanumericness (although would be interested in general solutions).

E.g. `"string#example[is-like="html"].selectors"`

would match to `[string, #, example, [, is, -, like, =", html, "]., selectors]`

Any idea how to do this in RegEx? Thanks!

Edit: I'll be using PHP's RegEx engine via `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\w+|\W+
```

*1 or more consequences of word characters **OR** One or more consequences of non-word characters*

**Output**:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => string
        [1] => #
        [2] => example
        [3] => [
        [4] => is
        [5] => -
        [6] => like
        [7] => ="
        [8] => html
        [9] => "].
        [10] => selectors
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html), for example in C#:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"\b");
```

If you want to avoid empty matches at the start/end of the string, combine it with [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"(?<!^)\b(?!$)");
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!^) # Assert we're not at the start of the string
\b     # Match a position between an alnum an a non-alnum character
(?!$)  # Assert we're not at the end of the string, either
```

A generic solution would look like this:

Let's say you want to split between digits (`\d`) and non-digits (`\D`). Then you could use

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?<=\D)(?=\d)");
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\d) # Assert that the previous character is a digit
(?=\D)  # and the next character is a non-digit.
|       # Or:
(?<=\D) # Assert that the previous character is a non-digit
(?=\d)  # and the next character is a digit.
```